# HSQL Trigger unexpected token NEW

Tags: sql, triggers, hsqldb

I have the following trigger, that has been taken from an Oracle one that is working:

```
create trigger D_DOCUMENT before delete on DOCUMENT
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
    -- Further SQL
END;
```

This now being run in a HSQLDB framework.
I needed to add keyword ATOMIC, however the real sticking point is this REFERENCING NEW line.
When I run this I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: NEW
```

Looking at the documentation I really can't understand why this token is unexpected, so I'm confused as to why this is complaining about "NEW".
Commenting out the line does get the error to 'move along', however there seems to be something wrong with either the syntax, or it's some bug I've stumbled across.

Has anyone got this type of trigger working? Can you post a sample delete trigger to try?

Comment: Do you expect hsqldb be compatible with Oracle's product specific stored procedures?

Comment: No I don't and hence I have modified it from the original specification to HSQL's. This is possible using latest version of HSQL, so hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no NEW ROW in a BEFORE DELETE trigger. There is only an OLD ROW which is about to be deleted.

The error indicates this fact.

Comment: Thanks @fredt, that's the answer.